# Why is the GraphQL input type breaking the app

Tags: reactjs, graphql, next.js, apollo-server

I'm having a problem. I tried to test a mutation on an Apollo GraphQL API. It worked when I used the individual fields for the mutation type but when I replaced the fields with the input type I created, I get an error. It's inside a NextJS project, inside the api folder, so I'm using `apollo-server-micro`.

Error message

[image]

Working Code

```
const { gql } = require("apollo-server-micro");

export const typeDefs = gql`
  type Appointment {
    id: ID!
    firstName: String
    lastName: String
    email: String
    phoneNumber: String
  }

  type Query {
    appointments: [Appointment]
    appointment(id: Int): Appointment
  }

  type Mutation {
    bookAppointment(
      firstName: String!
      lastName: String
      email: String
      phoneNumber: String
    ): Appointment
  }

  input AppointmentInput {
    firstName: String!
    lastName: String
    email: String
    phoneNumber: String
  }
`;
```

Problem Code

```
const { gql } = require("apollo-server-micro");

export const typeDefs = gql`
  type Appointment {
    id: ID!
    firstName: String
    lastName: String
    email: String
    phoneNumber: String
  }

  type Query {
    appointments: [Appointment]
    appointment(id: Int): Appointment
  }

  type Mutation {
    bookAppointment(appointment: AppointmentInput): Appointment
  }

  input AppointmentInput {
    firstName: String!
    lastName: String
    email: String
    phoneNumber: String
  }
`;
```

Resolver

```
export const resolvers = {
  Query: {
    appointments: async (parent, args, { prisma }) => {
      return prisma.appointment.findMany();
    },
    appointment: async (parent, args, context) => {
      return context.prisma.appointment.findUnique({ where: { id: args.id } });
    },
  },

  Mutation: {
    bookAppointment: async (parent, args, context) => {
      const id = +Math.floor(Math.random() * 5001) + 1000;
      const booking = context.prisma.appointment.create({
        data: {
          id: id,
          firstName: args.firstName,
          lastName: args.lastName,
          email: args.email,
          phoneNumber: args.phoneNumber,
        },
      });
      return booking;
    },
  },
};
```

Comment: mutation resolver code not updated - bad/missing args passed into prisma

Comment: Exactly, when I run the mutation passing the fields to the input type, AppointmentInput and using the input, it doesn't work. When I use the fields directly in the mutation it works and accepts the args. Ran this morning in another project, using regular react and Apollo with Prisma, and it worked as expected.

Comment: What does your resolver look like?

Comment: I added the resolver above, sorry for not including it the first time.

Answer (score 0):

You could/should have/use decomposed variables before change:

```
const { firstName, lastName, email, phoneNumber } = args;
```

and use simply/directly `firstName`, `lastName` ...

Change would be trivial:

```
const { firstName, lastName, email, phoneNumber } = args.appointment;
```

or

```
const { appointment: { firstName, lastName, email, phoneNumber } } = args;
```

... but you can also shorten it all:

```
const booking = context.prisma.appointment.create({
  data: {
    id, ...args.appointment 
  },
```